# Does AWS trusted advisor runs automatically?

Tags: amazon-web-services

In AWS console trusted advisor screen, I am unable to find the option to run the trusted advisor manually. Does AWS trusted advisor runs automatically? If so, how often it will run to check the AWS configurations?

Answer (score 5):

AWS states in their FAQ how they handle (automatic) refreshes for Trusted Advisor:

> **Q: How often can I refresh my Trusted Advisor result?**
>
> You can refresh a check 5 minutes after it was last refreshed. You can refresh individual checks or refresh all the checks at once by choosing "Refresh All" in the top-right corner of the summary dashboard.
>
> When you visit the Trusted Advisor dashboard, any checks that have not been refreshed in the last 24 hours are automatically refreshed; this can take a few minutes. The date and time of the last refresh is displayed to the right of the check title.
>
> In addtion, for customers with Business or Enterprise Support plans, the Trusted Advisor data is automatically refreshed weekly.

In addition they offer an [API endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awssupport/latest/APIReference/API_RefreshTrustedAdvisorCheck.html) and [AWS CLI integration](http://docs.amazonaws.cn/cli/latest/reference/support/refresh-trusted-advisor-check.html) to manually refresh Trusted Advisor checks. For the AWS CLI that looks like:

```
aws support refresh-trusted-advisor-check --check-id <value>
```